# User state when app is closed, removed iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7.1

I have an App where the first time its run, it opens a settings page. Simple thats done. 
when you put the app in the background and you rerun it doesnt open the settings page - which is correct, but when you double press the button and swipe the app away it brings it back to when it was installed in the first place so the settings page opens.

I have done all of this with NSUserDefaults. 
So in DidFinishLaucningWithOptions i have put an IF statement, so if the boolforKey is blank (!never used) then set it to YES and run the settings page. 
When the settings page has been used it sets the boolforkey back to NO, so it doesnt run again when you relaunch the app to the foreground.

but when you swipe the app away it must reset the NSUSerDefault to YES and it shows the settings page.

Can anyone suggest where I should set the NSUSerDefault to NO so when its relauched from swiping it away it works.

Anyhelp please ?

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Use this method in the app delegate:

```
- (void)applicationWillResignActive:(UIApplication *)application
```

According to Apple's [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/uiapplicationdelegate_protocol/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/UIApplicationDelegate/applicationWillResignActive%3a):

> This method is called to let your app know that it is about to move
>   from the active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of
>   temporary interruptions (such as an incoming phone call or SMS
>   message) or when the user quits the app and it begins the transition
>   to the background state. An app in the inactive state continues to run
>   but does not dispatch incoming events to responders.

Comment: Yes, this page has some great visuals as well to help you get an idea of the lifecycle.

[App States and Multitasking](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html)